# How To Remove Tab Highlighting in vim

Tags: python, vim

Hello I am trying to personalize vim and ran into this problem
every white space is highlighted i tried to search for fixes
like using `:noh`,`:nohlsearch` but those did not work[image]

Here is my .vimrc file

```
:nohlsearch 
syntax on
set noerrorbells
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undofile
set incsearch
set colorcolumn=80
set backspace=indent,eol,start
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged') 
" Neovim lsp Plugins
Plug 'rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes'
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
Plug 'tweekmonster/gofmt.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plug 'mbbill/undotree'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'stsewd/fzf-checkout.vim'
Plug 'vuciv/vim-bujo'
Plug 'tpope/vim-dispatch'
Plug '/home/mpaulson/personal/vim-apm'
Plug 'theprimeagen/vim-be-good'
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
Plug 'colepeters/spacemacs-theme.vim'
Plug 'sainnhe/gruvbox-material'
Plug 'phanviet/vim-monokai-pro'
Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: I'm not able to open the image right now. Just to make sure does changing `colorscheme` or `filetype` make a difference?

Comment: When you do `/\t`, does it match? I think it’s because you have `expandtab`, but those are probably actual tabs.

Comment: Do you have a mix of spaces and tabs on those lines? Try using `:set list` to see which characters are actually there... If it's a mix of spaces and tabs, then it's a warning enabled by vim-polyglot. It's correct to warn you, since mixing spaces and tabs is wrong in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listchars feature might have been enabled.
Try disabling it with `:set nolist`